# HTML class not responding to jQuery action after using js.erb to render page after AJAX call Rails app

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, erb

I am writing an app that has follow functionality and this is done with a AJAX call to the controller. After that call I render the opposite button of the one that was clicked using js.erb that renders the button I want to show. However, I have a hover functionality on my button that after I click this button, the hover no longer works. It is the right class of button but the jQuery I use to change the state of the button does not work.

Here is some code, my jQuery:

```
unfollow_button = $(".unfollow-button");
unfollow_button.hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).text("Unfollow");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).text("Following");
    }
);
```

This is my view:

```
<% if current_user.following?(f) %>
<%= link_to "Following", user_unfollow_teacher_path(f), :class => "btn unfollow-button", :remote => true %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to "Follow", user_follow_teacher_path(f), :class => "btn btn-primary purple-button", :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the js.erb file I use:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
```

And this the partial that get rendered is:

```
<%= link_to "Following", user_unfollow_teacher_path(@user), :class => "unfollow-button btn", :remote => true %>
```

The jQuery works fine when I click unfollow, then after I follow again and have the button set to the unfollow-button the hover action stops working.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to call that jquery code again in your `js.erb` file:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
$(".unfollow-button").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).text("Unfollow");
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("btn-danger");
        $(this).text("Following");
    }
);
```

Its best not to have the code in multiple places, so I usually setup an initializer and that allows me to recall the same code in my .erb files (code below is in coffeescript, but you can convert it to js [here](http://js2coffee.org/)

init.js.coffee

```
(myApp, $, undefined_) ->
  myApp.init = myApp.init or {}

  myApp.init.followHover = ->
    $(".unfollow-button").hover(#code here)

) window.myApp = window.myApp or {}, jQuery

$ ->
  myApp.init.followHover()
```

Then when you need it again in js.erb just call it!

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/follow')) %>")
myApp.init.followHover()
```

Comment: Awesome! It works, gonna go with the hacky solution first and refactor later.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate your javascript events like this. Now the JQUERY won't break after AJAX calls and this works beautifully with turbolinks turned on.

```
    $(function() {

      $("#follow_form").parent().delegate(".unfollow-button", "mouseover",
        function(){
          $(this).val("Unfollow");
          $(this).addClass("btn-danger");
        }
      );

      $("#follow_form").parent().delegate(".unfollow-button", "mouseout",
        function(){
          $(this).val("Following");
          $(this).removeClass("btn-danger");
        }
      );

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the jQuery event listener isn't aware of the newly inserted DOM elements. Try using `unfollow_button.on('hover', function()...`

More info: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Your reason makes sense, I just don't know how I'll fix this. on didn't work :(